# java conditional logging with decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a use case where I need to do conditional loggging, so what that means is lets say I have method bark() which would accept Animal and if I pass dog it should log something like The dog is barking. So based on the type of object the log statement would change. One thing that can be done is check the type of object and based on that do the logging but that might not be a very efficient way of doing. So in any way would this use case be solved with decorator pattern or is there a better way of solving this.

Comment: Your whole modeling is very bad. Only dogs bark, so `bark` should be a method of `Dog`. Even if it were a more generic method, like `makeSound`, it then should then be a method of `Animal`. It makes no sense doing `bark(dog)` or `makeSound(dog)`. It should be `dog.makeSound()`. And it should be overridden to bark inside of `Dog.class`, and then it could log it's own log statement.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly saying, I found it quite opinion based and I don't think I would like to create a class to wrap around the `Animal` object.

But I find the Decorator Pattern useful when you have already written most of the code and suddenly you feel that you should have done something extra. So refactoring here becomes a tedious work. I find these kind of situations best for decorator pattern.

From your question:

> I have a use case where I need to do conditional loggging, so what
>   that means is lets say I have method bark() which would accept Animal

I would have used the same approach you are going with, but in a slightly different way...

---

You can create an interface named `SpeakingAnimal` and play around with it:

```
public interface SpeakingAnimal extends Animal {
    public void saySomething();
}

public class Doge implements SpeakingAnimal {
    public void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("So Java! Very Technic! Wow!");
    }
}
```

If you do not choose to extend `SpeakingAnimal` with `Animal`, you can:

```
public interface SpeakingAnimal {
    public void saySomething();
}

public class Dog implements Animal, SpeakingAnimal {
    public void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Doggy woof woof");
    }
}
```

So you can do this in your `bark()` method:

```
public void bark(Animal animal) {
    if (animal instanceof SpeakingAnimal)
        ((SpeakingAnimal) animal).saySomething();
}
```